# kernel bug at kernel/auditsc.c:1532

Tags: centos, kernel, linux-kernel, kernel-panic, rust

I'm on a 32 bit CentOS 7 machine.

I just do these commands and a kernel panic is observed:

```bsh
cd repos/
git clone https://github.com/SergioBenitez/Rocket
cd Rocket/
cd examples/hello_world/
cargo run -v
```

> kernel BUG at kernel/auditsc.c:1532!
>
> invalid opcode: 0000 [#1] SMP

What should I do? Where to report? I have no idea how to react.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Solution

Dumped 32 bit CentOS 7 and installed 32 bit Ubuntu 16.04 LTS which seems to be the last 32 bit Ubuntu LTS.

No kernel panic is observed with 32 bit Ubuntu 16.04 LTS while installing Rust or building/running Rust applications.

#### History

This 32 bit machine previously had Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and 14.04 LTS and the experience was smooth. So, 16.04 LTS looks to be a sensible choice.

#### Service/update

The only problem is that Ubuntu 16.04 LTS is going to be out-of-service in April 2021. So no more updates! To work around that, another solution might be to install [32 bit Debian](https://www.debian.org/distrib/) on the machine. The machine didn't have any Debian before, so anything might happen :(

## Final solution

#### openSUSE Tumbleweed 32 bit

Eventually I installed openSUSE Tumbleweed 32-bit which is updated regularly due to being a rolling release. It works great =)

Answer (score 1):

Granted you're running the latest kernel version (i.e. `yum update 'kernel*'`), you file a bug report here:

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/enter_bug.cgi?product=Red%20Hat%20Enterprise%20Linux%207

RedHat is unlikely to dedicate any resources to solving the issue unless it affects multiple customers or you yourself have a paid subscription for RHEL 7.

Kernel bugs like this could even happen due to stray charged particles from space hitting your memory modules and flipping memory bits, so unless you can consistently reproduce it, I wouldn't even bother.

Comment: The error happened maybe 3 or 4 times, as far as I remember :(

Comment: You can try filing a bug report but you're at the mercy of RedHat developers. It's unlikely you can get help elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error while building Qt5 with webkit from source on CentOS 7 32-bit. Adding "audit=0" kernel parameter resolved the issue.